# How to convert a Rect ToString, while limiting decimal places?

Tags: c#, tostring, rect

Is there a simple format provider that will return a Rect structure `ToString` and limit the number of decimal places?

```
System.Windows.Rect myRect;
```

If I use `myRect.ToString()`, it returns

```
myRect: 0.0139211136847734,0.109375,0.995359599590302,1
```

I want this, limiting numbers to two decimal places but `myRect.ToString("D2")` does not compile

```
 myRect: 0.01,0.10,0.99,1
```

Note: I don't care about rounding, rounded or truncated is fine.

Comment: Can't you round the digits while assigning them to the Rect object?

Comment: @patsy, Thanks but I really don't want to lose the precision in the values. It's just that the user doesn't need to see that may digits.

Comment: I have updated my answer so the `Rect.ToString` method can be used directly (with a custom formatter) to return the result you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extension method:

```
public static class RectExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringRounded(this System.Windows.Rect rect)
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", 
            Math.Round(rect.X, 2), Math.Round(rect.Y, 2), 
            Math.Round(rect.Width, 2), Math.Round(rect.Height, 2));
    }
}
```

and then call `myRect.ToStringRounded();`

Don't forget to include the namespace of the extension method

Comment: I like this approach. I was hoping there was a less, brute force method, but c'est la vie.

Comment: Instead of rounding explicitely, I'd simply suggest `{0:F2}`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to implement your own custom *format provider*, so that you can use the standard `ToString` method of the rect object. In order to do this, you need to define a custom formatter class that implements the [IFormatProvider interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IFormatProvider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [ICustomFormatter interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ICustomFormatter.aspx). This ways you could implement your own `ToString("D2")` solution. An example solution of the custom formatter for your needs can look like this:

```
public class CustomRectFormat : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // the custom format
    public string Format(string fmt, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) 
    {
        // the method processes every part of the Rect members
        var chunk = arg.ToString();
        // skip delimiters
        if (chunk != ";")
        {
            // round doubles if possible
            Double part = 0.0;
            if (Double.TryParse(chunk, out part))
            {
                return Math.Round(part, 2).ToString();
            }
        }
        return chunk;
    }
}
```

Usage with the standard `Rect.ToString` method:

```
var rect = new Rect();
rect.X = 0.5678;
rect.Width = 1.2345;
Console.WriteLine(rect.ToString(new CustomRectFormat()));
```

The output is as desired:

```
0,57;0;1,23;0
```

---

Another possible solution would be to implement your own `Rect` *wrapper* class. Since `Rect` is sealed, it can't be subclassed, but you can still create  class that *mimics* the original class. In this class you can *overwrite* the `ToString` method with rounding:

```
public class CustomRect
{
    private Rect rect;

    public CustomRect() : this(new Size(0.0, 0.0))
    {
    }

    public CustomRect(Size size)
    {
        rect = new Rect(size);
    }

    public Double Width
    {
        get { return rect.Width; }
        set { rect.Width = value; }
    }

    public Double X
    {
        get { return rect.X; }
        set { rect.X = value; }
    }

    public Double Y
    {
        get { return rect.Y; }
        set { rect.Y = value; }
    }

    public Double Height
    {
        get { return rect.Height; }
        set { rect.Height = value; }
    }

    public String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}", Math.Round(rect.X, 2), Math.Round(rect.Y, 2), Math.Round(rect.Width, 2), Math.Round(rect.Height));
    }
}
```

Usage of the class:

```
var rect1 = new CustomRect();
var rect2 = new Rect();
rect1.X = 0.123;
rect1.Width = 3.2342342342342;
rect1.Height = 0.987234876234;
rect2.X = 0.123;
rect2.Width = 3.2342342342342;
rect2.Height = 0.987234876234;
Console.WriteLine(rect1.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(rect2.ToString());
```

And the output is:

```
0,12;0;3,23;1
0,123;0;3,2342342342342;0,987234876234
```

This solution has the problem, that you need to use everywhere the custom class and not the predefined `Rect` class.

---

Another good approach would be to create (as suggested by @Flat Eric) an extension method that does this for all objects of the `Rect` class. The downside of this approach is, that you can't use the `ToString` method when needed.

You need to decide which solution is more suitable for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a more recent development, I don't know, but as of today, this works flawlessly:

```
$"rect={rect:F2}"
```

Of course, the older `String.Format` approach would do the same.

```
String.Format("{0:F2}", rect);
```